# Why does my manual code bone rotation not work when a animation is active/playing?

Tags: godot

So, I have a rigged character and created a simple walk animation in blender and export it as gltf 2.0 to godot. And in godot I also via code rotate a bone of that rigged model. The bone rotates correctly when there is no walk animation active/playing.

But the moment I walk the bone which I rotate via code doesn't rotate. And I think it's cuz the Animation overrides the bone rotations ? I tried deleting the keyframe for that particular bone in both godot and blender but that didn't work. Anyone know how I can make both my code rotation of the bone and the animation work simultaneously ? If there is a better way or I am doing wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering from the top of my head: You need to change which pose you use.

You don't want to set the same that the animation sets because it overwrites it. Instead use a different pose. They compose into the final position. See [How to get global world coordinates of bone in Godot GDscript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68386221/402022) and [.translated function not working in Godot / best way to change position of bone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68400486/402022).

If I recall correctly you need to use custom pose ([`set_bone_custom_pose`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_skeleton.html#class-skeleton-method-set-bone-custom-pose)), because the animation sets the pose ([`set_bone_pose`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_skeleton.html#class-skeleton-method-set-bone-pose)).

Comment: Thx get_bone_custom_pose and set_bone_custom_pose helped !